# Getting information from XML Tag with PHP

Tags: php, xml, session

So I have this XML File.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<user>
  <resource>
    <reswood>150</reswood>
    <resstone>150</resstone>
    <ressteel>150</ressteel>
    <limit>1000</limit>
  </resource>
</user>
```

And this is the php file.

```
<?php
session_start();
$userlogin = $_SESSION['username'];

$xml=simplexml_load_file('data/' . $userlogin . '/' . $userlogin . '.xml');

echo $xml->reswood;
echo $xml->resstone;
echo $xml->ressteel;
?>
```

alright so I have changed to simple xml and now it just displays blank...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't understand the question... "wood tag:" isn't valid PHP and would error out.  Unless you wanted the output to actually say "echo" and stuff.  But either way, you should really use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) instead of load to read the XML file, and then you can use [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) to navigate and access the XML data far easier.

Comment: Sorry the wood tag isnt apart of the code ill just edit that sorry, what i mean is that i want to get the data from inside the res tag inside resources tag but only if the name = wood or stone or steel

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense for them to be associative arrays?  Like $res['wood'] instead of $res_wood?  To leave open options for different names?  I'm still not 100% sure what you're trying to output.  If the three tags are next to each other, why bold, then unbold, then bold, then unbold, etc?

Comment: alright i have completely changed the question i have gone with simple php but now its not displaying the data its just blank

Comment: You were close... you have to include the full XML path (sans the root), so instead of "echo $xml->reswood;", you'd do "echo $xml->resource->reswood;"